# collecting column of multidimensional array to set

Tags: java, java-8, set, java-stream, collectors

I have an attribute `this.sudoku` which is a `int[9][9]` array.
I need to get a column of this into a set.

```
Set<Integer> sudoku_column = IntStream.range(0, 9)
                                      .map(i -> this.sudoku[i][column])
                                      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I expect a columns values in this set. but it says that `Collectors.toSet()` cannot be applied to this collect function in the chain. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Careful when collecting to a set. Apart from the `mapToObj` error explained in the answers, the `Set` implementation returned by `Collectors.toSet()` doesn't impose an order to its elements. Thus, you might lose the order of the rows, i.e. the first element of the returned set wouldn't match the element that corresponds to the first row. You'd better collect to a `List` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`IntStream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#map-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) consumes an `IntUnaryOperator` which represents an operation on a **single int-valued operand** that produces an **int-valued result** thus the result is an `IntStream`, however `IntStream` does not have the `collect` overload you're attempt to use, which means you have a couple of options; i.e. either use [`IntStream#collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-):

```
IntStream.range(0, 9)
         .collect(HashSet::new, (c, i) -> c.add(sudoku[i][column]), HashSet::addAll);
```

or use `mapToObj` to transform from `IntStream` to `Stream<Integer>` which you can then call `.collect(Collectors.toSet())` upon.

```
IntStream.range(0, 9)
        .mapToObj(i -> this.sudoku[i][column])
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 4):

[`IntStream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#map(java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator)) takes an [`IntUnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/IntUnaryOperator.html) which is a function to transform an `int` to another `int`.

It's fine if you want to continue with an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html). But if you need to collect the stream into a `Set<Integer>`, you need to turn your [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) into a stream of boxed `int`s, a [`Stream<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html), by [`IntStream#boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed()).

```
.map(i -> this.sudoku[i][column])
.boxed()
.collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

> `Collectors.toSet()` cannot be applied to this `collect` function in the chain

`Collectors.toSet()` return a `Collector` which doesn't fit the signature of the single `collect(Supplier, ObjIntConsumer, BiConsumer)` method in `IntStream`. Though, it's suitable for [`Stream.collect(Collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)).